# how to use "for" in awk procedure?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a task: Write a script for the summation of integers stored in the file. Form a call script: example: `sum a.txt 3 4`

The input file can contain several columns of integer. The individual columns are separeted by speces or tabs. The script should sum a appropriate columns and write the result to stdout. So when we have `sum a.txt 3 4` we need to add the number of the third and fourth columns file.

So I do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=( "$@" )
let LA=${#array1[@]}-1
awk '{for(i=1;i<=$LA;i++)y+=$'${array1[i]}'; print y}' a.txt
```

but I have an error: `awk: : 1unexpected character '.'`

Please help is there another way to add up the number of columns whose number are given in the procedure call script?

On this forum a got answer to do this the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v col1=$2 -v col2=$3 '{sum1 += $col1; sum2 += $col2} END{print sum1,sum2}' $1
```

but what if we don't know the amount of numbers of columns that will be given in the procedure example: `./sum a.txt 2 3 ... n` (maybe I need use `for` but how?)

Comment: You can use the AWK variable `NF` to get the number of columns (number of fields) in the current record. This would look like `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)...` You can then use `$i` to refer to the particular field you are iterating through.

Comment: It is not clear that all given columns should be added in each-and-every rows (`y` should be zeroed then) or the columns should be added. The first script seems to add by row, the second adds by column. In my answer I implemented the second possible interpretation.

Comment: I have a solution (see below) that takes an arbitrary number `n` of column numbers and eventually prints the `n` sums of the corresponding fields, summed line by line.  Is it _exactly_ what you need or not?

Comment: @Lucyna In your Q you've not specified what to do if the script user gives more than once a column number on invocation as, e.g., in `sh sum_cols.sh int_table.txt 2 5 2 7`.  I can think of three possibilities: with reference to my example you could (1) ignore the repetitions and output the sum for the three distinct columns, (2) output four results, one of them repeated twice and (3) given that a column is specified by a tuple `(j,n) where` `j` is the column number and `n` the number of repetitions, output for each _distinct_ column the value `n*sum(table[i,j], i)`. Please, which is your spec?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need AWK for this. Bash is enough:

```
$ cat data.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
$ ./csum.sh $(seq 0 5) < data.txt
21 24 27 30 33 36
$ cat csum.sh
#! /bin/bash
SUM=()
S=0
for N in "$@"; do
  SUM[$S]=0
  ((S++))
done
while IFS=$'\n' read LINE ; do
  COLS=($LINE)
  S=0
  for C in "$@"; do
    SUM[$S]=$(expr ${SUM[S]} + ${COLS[C]})
    ((S++))
  done
done
echo ${SUM[*]}
```

Comment: @EdMorton With the same argumentation you can say, this must be done with [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), because only with ANTLR you can specify the "right" parser for the data, you want to parse. Using fewer tools can be a value on its own.

Comment: @EdMorton Are you the one who defines what Unix is? Is Solaris which is coming with Java out of the box a Unix?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I read your updated question, I think you want:

```
file: my.awk

#!/bin/bash
eval "awk '{print \$$2+\$$3}' $1"
```

This will add the columns together you pass in.

```
E.g. cat num.txt
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1


$>my.awk num.txt 2 3
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
```

And if you want more columns you can select them from the command line, to add further columns - the following adds columns 4,5,1,3,1 like this:

```
$> my.awk num.txt 4 5+\$1+\$3+\$1
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
```

Value is 16 since the respective values of columns 4,5,1,3,1 is (2+1+5+3+5) = 16. You can append as many columns in that manner in any order you want and it will add them all together.

Or if you want here is an easier version, with this you just put the filename followed by the columns you wish to add up:

```
file: my2.awk

#!/bin/bash
eval "awk '{print $(echo "${*:2}" | sed -r 's/\b[0-9]*\b/\$&+/g;s/\+$//')}' $1"

$> my2.awk num.txt 1 5 2 3
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
```

Comment: I think this prints `NF-1` for each line.

Comment: Yea, I tested it on only a one line text and the OP wording of this is not very clear to me - I changed it to print the number of columns for only for the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Shell variables are not expanded in [single quoted strings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02), like your [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) program, you have to set a variable with the [option `-v`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_04) followed by `var=value`.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" < 2 ]; then
    echo "$0:" not enough arguments
    exit 1;
fi
FILE=$1;
shift 1;
awk -v A="$*" 'BEGIN { N = split(A,a," "); }\
               { y = 0; for(i = 1; i <= N; i++) y += $(a[i]); print y; }' "$FILE"
```

[`shift 1`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#shift) shifts the arguments left 1. ex. `$2 -> $1`

`BEGIN { N = split(A,a," "); }` [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13) the string `A` into an array `a` by spaces.

`{y = 0; for(i = 1; i <= N; i++) y += $(a[i]); print y; }` zeros `y`, adds every field numbered `a[i]` to `y`, and finally prints `y`;

However your script is simple enough to just use [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    if (ARGC < 2) {
        print $0, ": not enough arguments";
        exit 1;
    }
    for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
        a[i] = ARGV[i] + 0;
        delete ARGV[i];
    }
}
{
    tmp = 0;
    for (i in a) {
        tmp += $(a[i]);
    }
    print tmp;
}
```

`a[i] = ARGV[i] + 0` sets `a[i]` to the **number** `ARGV[i] + 0`

`delete ARGV[i]` removes [`ARGV[i]`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03), this prevents [`ARGV[i]`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) from being treated as a file name to open.

It may be worth noting that most versions of [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) are quite a bit smaller than `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fully flagged solution. The bash script test.sh looks like this:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<ARGC;++i)s[i]+=$ARGV[i]}ENDFILE{for(i=2;i<ARGC;++i)printf("%d ",s[i]);print"";exit}' "$@"
```

Input

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Command line:

```
test.sh inputfile 3 4 5
```

Output:

```
27 30 33
```

The C like ARGC[1] contains the name of the input file (BTW it is identical to FILENAME in this case), others above 1 contain the numbers. The `ENDFILE` has to exist as there is no such file as `3`. But before this it prints the summed column values.

Referencing to ceving's comment, a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version can be enough (if the input file is small. Less then cca 100 lines). In this case no external utility needed.

```
file="$1"; shift
cols=($@)
while read -r t; do
  arr=($t)
  for((i=0;i<$#;++i)){ ((sum[i]+=arr[cols[i]-1]));}
done < "$file"
echo "${sum[@]}"
```

The command line and output is the same.

Comment: Note that `ENDFILE` is only available in `gawk`, and perhaps `gawk` derivatives.

Comment: @kdhp: You are right! On many Linuxes [tag:awk] is just a symbolic link to gawk (sometimes not directly). As OP also tagged [tag:bash] I assumed that the OP's awk is really gawk. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @kdhp: Actually it seems that setting `ARGC` to 2 the `ENDFILE` can be changed to `END`. [tag:awk] can be started like: `BEGIN{N=ARGC;ARGC=2}` and `N` can be used instead of `ARGC`. It work with [tag:gawk], but I could not test with [tag:awk].

Comment: It is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) and works with `nawk`.

Comment: If you use the `ARGC` method, you may want to add some checks similar `if(ARGV[i]+0!=0)sum+=$(ARGV[i]+0)`. If this is not done passing a non numeric argument results in an uninformative error message given to the user of the utility.

Comment: I can't understand the logic (without putting in more effort than I care to) but won't that awk script open and produce some kind of output for files named 3, 4, and 5 if they exist in the directory you run the script from? if you want to pass all of the shell args to awk then you need to separate them in a BEGIN section and empty the contents of ARGV[] for each non-file argument.

Comment: @EdMorton It works under the assumption that `awk` is `gawk`, `gawk` opens files sequentially, and `gawk`'s `ENDFILE` occurs *before* the next file is opened.

Comment: So it's passing values as if they were file names and relying on gawk's ENDFILE to exit out of the file list before it gets to the first arg that's not really a file. I guess that will function but it's not exactly obvious! If you want to pass non-file names in the arg list then I'd highly recommend not doing it the above way but instead just separating the non-file values out in the BEGIN section and clearing ARGV[]s as you go - the result will be much clearer and portable to all modern awks (i.e. not gawk-specific).

Comment: @TrueY If by chance a user repeats `n` times a column number in the command line, the final result for that column will be multiplied by `n`.  Is such behavior a feature or a bug?  If I were in your shoes I'd say it is _an undocumented feature_, and I'll add a note to document it... Ciao

Comment: @gboffi: User can repeat any number in the command line. As the original Q was not specified strictly, it can be acceptable for any reason.

Comment: Your awk solution outputs one value for each distinct column number, `n*sum(table[i,j], i)` while your shell solution outputs, for each column on the command line, `sum(table[i,j], i)`.  Of course «As the original Q was not specified strictly» the OP can chose either one or accept both. It's just that the OP should be aware of the alternatives. Ciao

Comment: @gboffi: I think you had misinterpreted sg. Bot calculates the sum of the specified column(s). If one is given multiple times then it will output the same result multiple times. I tested with the following args (with [tag:gawk] on Linux): `inputfile 3 3 4 4 5 5 `. The result is identical: `27 27 30 30 33 33` which is the original goal. Do You got different results?

Comment: @gboffi: I think I understood what your problem is. The sum variable (`s`) is based on the order of the argument, nut the number in the Nth argument. So it works properly, not multiples the sum of the column. I use `$ARGV[i]` and if `ARGV[2] == 3` then it interpreted as `$3`, summing the 3rd column into `s[2]`. Only if I would use `s[$ARGV[i]]+=$ARGV[i]` you would be right. But I do not do that.

Comment: @EdMorton: Understood! Thanks for the comment! If You set `ARGC=2` in BEGIN then you can get similar result in a shorter way.

Comment: @TrueY is that behavior defined by POSIX? I would think that might only work in some awks, like decrementing NF to delete the last field(s) of $0.

Comment: @EdMorton: Maybe you are right! I definitely did not tested on all [tag:awk] versions.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide sample input and expected output for us to test against so this may or may not work for you but it is the correct approach if I understand your question correctly:

```
file="$1"
shift
awk -v fldNrs="$*" '
BEGIN { split(fldNrs,flds) }
{ sum=0; for (idx in flds) sum += $(flds[idx]); print sum }
' "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### *Disclaimer*

My script  ***ignores*** column number repetitions in the command line.

If the OP requires a different behavior, other excellent answers are available that implement other possible treatments of repetition.

```
% cat sum_cols.sh 

file="$1";shift

# next 3 lines, we build, eg, beg="BEGIN{a[3]=0;a[5]=0;a[6]=0;}"
beg="BEGIN{"
for n in "$@"; do beg=$(printf "%sa[%d]=0;" "$beg" "$n") ; done
beg="$beg""}"

# The awk program below  is based on the "for(i in a)" statement
# "for(i in a) is a loop over the indexes of the array "a"
# we loop for every line to accumulate the sum
#         and at the end to print our results

awk "$beg {for(i in a) a[i]+=\$i} END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}" $file

% cat integers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 
111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 
% sh sum_cols.sh integers 2 5 7
2 684
5 720
7 744
% # EDIT Note that a repeated column number in the command line is ignored 
% sh sum_cols.sh integers 2 5 2 7
2 684
5 720
7 744
%
```

#### *edit*

The original question left unspecified what to do in case the user of the script repeats  a column number in the command line, as in `sh col.sh integers 2 5 2 7` above.

My take was to ignore the repetition, while in other solutions (e.g., Ed Morton's or TrueY's ones) you  get, for `n` appearances of column number `j` the result `n*sum(matrix(i,j), i)`.

I must confess that in my case the choice of one particular behavior was incidental...